# Equivalence of Definitions of lim inf of Sequence of Sets

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Prove : $\{w : w \in A_n \text{ for all $n$ except a finite number}\}= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$.
I am trying to prove these two definitions are equivalent but I am having trouble.

---

**Proof so far:** Let $x \in \{w : w \in A_n \text{ for all $n$ except a finite number}\}$. Then  $x$ is in all but a finite number of $A_n$. Now pick the largest $m$ such that $x$ is not in $A_m$. Then as $x \in A_j$ for all $j >m$. So $ x\in \bigcap_{j=m}^{\infty} A_j$. It follows that $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{j=n}^{\infty}A_j$

Comment: The simplest way to check these is to expand out the lhs

Comment: @TimothyBrown so your first half of the proof is perfectly good.  Are you struggling to show the reverse inclusion?  If not, what exactly is your question about the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument given in the question is correct and it shows that
$$
\{w : w \in A_n \text{ for all $n$ except a finite number}\} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k
$$
It remains to show that
$$
\{w : w \in A_n \text{ for all $n$ except a finite number}\} \supseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k.
$$
Given that you've written what you've written so far, I suspect you can do that.

You wrote

> Let $x \in \{w : w \in A_n \text{ for all $n$ except a finite number}\}$. Then  $x$ is in all but a finite number of $A_n$. Now pick the largest $m$ such that $x$ is not in $A_m$.

It seems to me that's a more complicated way of saying this than what is needed.  You could write

> Suppose $w \in A_n \text{ for all $n$ except a finite number}$. Now pick the largest $m$ such that $w$ is not in $A_m$. [etc.]

Answer (score 2):

Your proof so far is perfectly fine.  All you need to do is prove the reverse inclusion and you'll be set.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. I always thought this was the definition of $\liminf$. The proof so far is right. I would prefer to add to the last sentence 'Since this holds for some $m \ge 1$' and then use m in the indices instead of n.

---

The reverse inclusion can be proven as follows:

Suppose $\omega \in \bigcup_{m\ge1}\bigcap_{n\ge m} A_n$.

Then $\omega \in \bigcap_{n\ge 1} A_n$ or $\omega \in \bigcap_{n\ge 2} A_n$ or $\omega \in \bigcap_{n\ge 3} A_n$...

Case 1: $\omega \in \bigcap_{n\ge 1} A_n$

Then $\omega \in A_n \forall n$ except for a finite number of $A_n$'s i.e. 0

Case 2: $\omega \in \bigcap_{n\ge 2} A_n$

Then $\omega \in A_n \forall n$ except for a finite number of $A_n$'s i.e. 1

$$\vdots$$

Case m: $\omega \in \bigcap_{n\ge m} A_n$

Then $\omega \in A_n \forall n$ except for a finite number of $A_n$'s i.e. $m-1$

$$\vdots$$

QED